# How do I turn this into a custom infrastructure as code pipeline?

Tags: git, jenkins

I have a Source of Truth database with an api layer over it, that keeps track of, for instance, Subnets, Hosts, DNS, Host Allocations, etc. What I'd like to do is set up an infrastructure as code pipeline, where changes to yaml files in a git repo would call the correct APIs.

For instance, this diff would call the subnet.post api:

```
+ subnet:
+   cidr: 10.0.0.0/8
+   name: Really big CIDR
```

And this diff would call the subnet.delete api:

```
- subnet:
-   cidr: 10.0.0.0/8
-   name: Really big CIDR
```

I'm thinking:

- set up a git repo with Jenkins
- Have a Jenkins job that queries the source of truth and compares to the objects in the yaml file
- if objects are missing from the yaml file, delete them for source of truth
- if objects are not in the yaml but not source of truth, then add them

Answer (score 1):

I don't think my answer can cover your entire use case but anyway here it is:

For triggering Jenkins when a push to a repository happened I recommend [Generic Webhook Trigger Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Generic+Webhook+Trigger+Plugin). It helps you a lot with parsing the information Github/Bitbucket/Gitlab gives you when they trigger your pipeline.

For the query, you could simply use `sh curl ...` or have a look at the [HTTP Requests Plugin](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/http_request/)

Looking for changes in the YAML could be done by hand or you could use the [changelog](https://support.cloudbees.com/hc/en-us/articles/217630098-How-to-access-Changelogs-in-a-Pipeline-Job-) Jenkins provides in the pipeline.